# SQL Server 2008 - permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL Server and I wanted to create my first table there.

```
create table Employee
(
    ID smallint not null
)
```

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and Windows Authentication.

when I execute , it says :

```
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack! Good first question.  Others below indicate how to go about creating your first table. I'll provide a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx) to what Microsoft has to say about it.  just to back up their responses.  Pay particular attention to the Recommendations section....Do not create user objects in master. Otherwise, master must be backed up more frequently.  As to why not... read the article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you're trying to create the table in `master` database where you may not have permission to create table. However, to create your target database please follow below steps:

a. At your SQLQuery editor choose your target database (`Available Database` drop down list) and execute your sql query.

Or

b. Try with below statement:

```
USE YourTargetDatabaseName
GO
CREATE TABLE Employee ( ID SMALLINT NOT NULL)
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you want to create a table in the master database.

Did you create a new database first? If so, use this:

```
USE [MyNewDatabaseName]
GO

create table Employee ( ID smallint not null )
GO
```